# Using facebook login on multiple virtual machine website ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website https://en.mypen.net that allow people to login with facebook and google.

The website is hosted on AWS.
the problem is that when I have more then 1 virtaul machines, getSessionFromRedirect() returns a session only if Im redirected to the same machine. Because I have 3 machines now, it works only 33%.

The address is the same. Any idea why Its happening? Im using CNAME from en.mypen.net to elsatic beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the session information exists on the server. When you have 3 servers the session only exists on one of them. There are two possible solutions to your problem:

- Setup a [distributed session store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb/) so that when a session is created by one server it is made available to all the other servers. This is the most scalable and fault tolerant option.
- Enable [sticky sessions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-elastic-load-balancing-feature-sticky-sessions/). This is the quickest and easiest option. Just be aware that if Elastic Beanstalk scales down the number of instances, some sessions will be destroyed.

Comment: but im not even creating a session in this page. facebook SDK creating it for me? And if they are, can I change the way they create the session?

Comment: Authentication is happening via Facebook, but the server is still creating a session to track that the user has been authenticated.